# How to design a 915 MHz waveguide circulator?

Tags: electrical-engineering, rf-electronics

I would like to design a waveguide circulator.  I tried to design one but, my attempt was not successful.  My design used a cylindrical cavity with ferrite as region. I then connected 3 waveguides in 0,120 and -120 directions. Upon applying the excitation, I got a pathetic result.  I have referred to some more resources but can not resolve this problem.  Has anybody tried this before?

My design and its parameters are shown below

[image: Waveguide circulator design]

- Frequency of operation: 915 MHz
- Dielectric permittivity of material(ferrite): 14.2
- The height of cylinder: 5.5 mm
- Radius of cylinder 30 mm
- The waveguide cross section a = 20 mm
- The waveguide cross section b = 2.5 mm
- The length of waveguide l = 50 mm

Comment: Hi Sumith, to assist those who might be able to answer your question it would be helpful if you could provide links to the references you mention in your question

Comment: They are some  whitepapers. I can't disclose them. Sorry for that. But I can add my design with parameters I have used. Could you please wait for little time?

Comment: A waveguide with such tiny dimensions is going to have a lower cutoff frequency on the order of 10 GHz or so. See [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide_(electromagnetism)#Waveguide_in_practice). Why do you think it would be effective at 915 MHz? In any case, you'd probably get a more thorough answer on this on [EE.SE](http://http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DaveTweed, Sir, you are right. I calculated the same again. For 915MHz, the cross section 'a' should be more than 16cm. However I like to know how I can construct circulator with waveguides. Thank you.